# Prefix Postfix Infix Java expression evaluator

Tags: java, expression, evaluation

i have been working on an expression evaluator in java and out of frustration I have also come here to ask about it. I have rewritten it at least 15 times by now and each to no avail.

Basically I need to take a String in either prefix, infix or postfix and evaluate it to an integer. The expression can use any arithmetic operators included in java.

The problems im having:
- When i try to parse to an expression tree or parse them all to postfix i have problems with the monomial operators.
- I can't get it to identify a multi digit number as one number and subsequently it ruins the whole tree or it switches around the digits.
- I can't get the program to figure out where to put down the parentheses correctly and i can't get it to identify the beggining and end of the parentheses using a stack.

So basically the program needs to do this:

For any arbitrary numbers A B C D E F

Evaluate in prefix postfix and infix:

A-- + ++B - --C * D++ / E % F

For any arbitrary bits A B C D E F G and number n

Evaluate in prefix, postfix, and infix:
A & B | C ^ ~D

n >> A

n << A

My textbook isn't much help nor are the books i have ordered, I really can't understand how to do this, please help, even just an explanation of how to do it would be good enough for me. Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have successfully tokenized all your identifiers, operators, and literals, the next step would be to read a bit about recursive descent parsers. You can probably write one by hand for this case rather than trying to figure out how to use a parser generator.

Comment: Is there anywhere you can point me to learn about recursive descent parsing for this, i would think this must be a pretty common computer science project. =/

Comment: The Wikipedia article is a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser